# Java Swing line drawing program does not keep previous lines

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write a java swing program that draws lines (Coordinates are stored in a Points ArrayList). It does that, but it refreshes/erases the previous line. I'm wondering what I have to do to keep all lines.

Thanks for looking.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Draw extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Point> points;

    public Draw() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();

         MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {

             public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                 points.clear();
                 points.add(e.getPoint());
                 repaint();
             }

             public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                 points.add(e.getPoint());
                 repaint();
             }

             public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                 points.add(e.getPoint());
                 repaint();
             }

         };

         this.addMouseListener(adapter);
         this.addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (points.size() > 1) {
            Point p1 = points.get(0);

            for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++){
                Point p2 = points.get(i);
                g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
                p1 = p2;
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Draw draw = new Draw();
        frame.setContentPane(draw);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: how can you have "Peach()" constructor inside a "Draw" classs?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sometimes I name my classes ridiculous names out of boredom - changed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: is it intentional to clear the ArrayList when the mouse is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does that, but it refreshes/erases the previous line.

```
points.clear();
```

I would think the clear() method is removing all your previous points.

If you keep storing individual points the size of the List can get very large. Instead you may want to consider drawing directly to a BufferedImage. This way you don't need to store each point as a mouseDragged event is generated.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. The only problem with removing that is that it forms a line from the last part of the line to the new mouse press. Working on a way right now to fix it.

Comment: @user2411290, see edit about the drawing to a BufferedImage. The other approach is to have an ArrayList of ArrayLists. So each time you do a mousePressed you create a new ArrayList and add the points to it. Then the painting logic with iterate through each individual ArrayList to paint all the Points in the List.